# Filling blobs (shapes) with unique colors based on area

Tags: matlab, image-processing, shapes, fill, area

I have some shapes on an image that i've attempted to label according to their Area using a solution provided to me:

```
stats = regionprops(BW,'Area')
stats2 = regionprops(BW,'Centroid')

figure,imshow(BW)
for k = 1:numel(stats)
    xy = stats2(k).Centroid
    if (stats(k).Area>TH)
        text(xy(1),xy(2),'L') %// Large Shape
    else
        text(xy(1),xy(2),'S') %// Small Shape
    end
end
```

But it turns out the shapes are too small for the letters ( which would be too small even if I changed the font), I'm wondering if there's a way to do the thresholding to produce a colour code i.e change the filling of the shapes based on their area?

Comment: Do you mean filling the boundary or the entire shape with the color code? If it's just the boundary, then with the small shapes, it would almost be for the entire shape I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is inspiring enough for you -

```
%// Input image. This one is chosen as it is available in MATLAB image library
img = imread('coins.png'); 

%// Convert to binary image
BW = im2bw(img,0.4); %// 0.4 as binary thresehold worked for this specific image

%// Get area and pixel-list stats
stats = regionprops(BW,'Area');
stats2 = regionprops(BW,'PixelIdxList');

s1 = struct2array(stats);
[v1,v2,v3] = unique(s1);
num_colors = numel(v1);

%// Pixel values per channel for creating color codes
pix_per_ch = linspace(0,255,ceil(power(num_colors,1/3)));

%// Unique 3 color codes
all_color_codes = allcomb(pix_per_ch,pix_per_ch,pix_per_ch);
%// allcomb is a MATLAB File-exchange tool avaiialble at -
%// http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb

%// Unique 3 color codes for the number of shapes available
color_codes = all_color_codes(randi(size(all_color_codes,1),num_colors,1),:);

%// Sort these uniques colors based on their grayscale intensities
[~,ind]=sort(rgb2gray(uint8(permute(color_codes,[1 3 2]))));
sorted_color_codes = color_codes(ind,:);

%// Pre-allocate for the ouput image
out = uint8(255.*BW(:,:,ones(1,3)));

%// Assign each shape a unique color based on their areas
for k = 1:numel(stats)
    ind1 = stats2(k).PixelIdxList;
    indx = bsxfun(@plus,ind1,[0:2].*size(img,1)*size(img,2));
    color_code = sorted_color_codes(v3(k),:);
    color_code_ext = color_code(ones(1,numel(ind1)),:);
    out(indx) = color_code_ext;
end

%// Display input, output results
figure,
subplot(211),imshow(img),
title('Input Image')
subplot(212),imshow(out),
title('Output Image (Brighter colors represent larger shapes)')
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: +1 for sheer tenacity. Wish I had another +1 to give for the answer itself :)

Comment: @beaker Was indeed a bit of work involved, but then I don't mind Image Processing stuffs, so it sorta balances out :) Appreciate the Up BTW!! ;)